# Interrupted upgrade to 12.04  - "no upgrade possible" - how to fix?

Tags: 11.10, upgrade

The upgrade to "precise" was interrupted,and if I try to upgrade now,I get the message:"No upgrade possible with this tool"Where do I find the tool required to upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in a terminal:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```